# How to make a age calculation output age when datestring in different order

Tags: javascript, datetime

I would like to calculate a users age when a string is entered however it has to be in a particular order currently this works only in one order I would like it to be day/month/year, currently it only works in month/day/year

```
function getAge(dateString) {
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }
    return age;
}
console.log('age: ' + getAge("16/01/1972")); **//01/16/1972 works!**
```

Comment: Link to a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qfbe7s2g/

Comment: [new Date()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) takes a certain format.  You're going to have to just work with that and work with the string before you turn it into a date.  I would pick a solution off of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript).

Comment: [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) on allowed js date formats for new Date()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getAge(dateString) {
    var today = new Date();
    var dateData = dateString.split('/');
    var birthDate = new Date(dateData[2], +dateData[1] - 1, dateData[0]);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }
    return age;
}
console.log('age: ' + getAge("16/11/1972"));
```